# Run a job once at a specific time

Tags: cron, time

I'm trying to create a cron that will run one time at a specific time.

For simplicity, how can I create a cron that will run at 11:57PM and print "Hello" to the screen then delete itself? (Cent OS 5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need it to run just once, cron is not your tool.

```
at (1)               - queue, examine or delete jobs for later execution
```

E.g.:

```
# at 12:57PM
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo hello
at> <EOT>
job 2 at Mon Jan  2 12:57:00 2012
```

(Press ctrl+d when done entering commands)

**Scheduling relatively to now**

```
fbh@pinky:~$ at now + 5 min
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo moo
at> <EOT>
job 5 at Mon Jan  2 06:05:00 2012
```

And as always, read much more on how to use this tool in the man page for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **at**, the output of the command will be emailed to you. To output text to the current terminal do the following:

```
echo "echo 'hello' > `tty`" | at 11:57PM
echo "echo 'hello' > `tty`" | at now + 5 minutes
```

Note that when you use **now + x minutes**, the execution time will be rounded to the previous minute.